# How to apply javascript code on dynamiclly added elements using javascript not JQuery?

Tags: javascript

I wrote a code that transform each word in an article to a link, and i wanted to apply onclick() function on the new anchors but the code is not working..

here is the javascript code:

```
    <script>
var tarea = document.getElementById("t");
var div = document.getElementById('res');

var article = tarea.innerHTML;
var i=0;
    while(i<500 ){
var ind = article.indexOf(" ");
var curr = article.substring(0,ind);
article = article.substring(article.indexOf(" ")+1);
anch = "<a class='link' id='link' href='#' >" + curr+"</a>";
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + " " + anch;
    i++;
}



var element = document.getElementById('link');
element.onclick = function () { 
alert(element.innerHTML);

 };
</script>
```

Comment: I *guess* you are looking for `addEventListener`. Your question is really useless in its current state. Always add your code and detail the research efforts that you made. Also, having "not working" in your question somewhere suggests that your question is not useful.

Comment: @user3294011 We cant help without seeing what you have already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called event delegation. It can get complicated, but this is the basic concept. You can use anything that can identify the element, but I just used id here since that is the most simple.

```
var MY_DYNAMIC_EL_ID = 'dynamic';
window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var el = e.srcElement || e.target;
  if(el.id == MY_DYNAMIC_EL_ID) {
    alert('clicked');
  }
}
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.id = MY_DYNAMIC_EL_ID;
document.body.appendChild(el);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B7Ja9/6/